# How to set property or variable in constructor with Ninject (MVC3 web application)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

I have interface ITest and class Test, which implements ITest:

```
public Test : ITest{...}
```

I have such class:

```
public class MyClass
{
 ITest test;
 public MyClass(){...}
}
```

Is there any way to set new Test() example in test variable with Ninjection? I want to get rid of this code in constructor:

```
public MyClass()
{
 test = new Test();
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you use constructor injection, e.g.:

```
public class MyClass {
    private readonly ITest _test;

    [Inject]
    public MyClass(ITest test) {
        _test = test;
    }
}
```

This provides visibility of a class dependency, i.e. `MyClass` is dependent on an instance of `ITest`. Ninject will automatically handle this dependency injection for you as long as you have registered an instance of `ITest` with the container.

Alternatively, you could use property/field injection:

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass() { }

    [Inject]
    public ITest Test { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass {
    [Inject] private ITest _test;

    public MyClass() { }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain second example? I tried it, but it didn't work in my application.

Comment: I want to set example of Test() in property, but property value is null always.